# My touchpad scroll is not working in windows 10

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I just shifted from windows 8.1 to windows 10. My touchpad scroll was working with windows 8.1 but not with windows 10. I'm not able to find the settings for touchpad in control panel they only give options for mouse.

Comment: A lot of people have been reporting this problem. Is it Synaptics? Try updating the driver or rolling it back.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. search for touchpad setting. It would be under control panel --> devices -> mouse & touchpad setting and under that setting make sure that it has no delay (always on) in delay section and for choosing number of lines to be scrolled select 5 or 6 lines.